# Unable to start service intent Broadcast receiver Android

Tags: android, notifications, android-service

Like many others I get the following error of "Unable to start service Intent...not found"

I am setting a notification to run an activity once per day (in my tests it is set for 30 seconds).  Here is the notification code:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, OnNotificationReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.cancel(pi); // cancel any existing alarms

    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, notifyTime, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES/30, pi);
```

OnNotificationReceiver.class is:

```
public class OnNotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        WakeReminderIntentService.acquireStaticLock(context);
        Intent i = new Intent(context, NotificationService.class);
        context.startService(i);
    }
```

NotificationService is:

```
public class NotificationService extends WakeReminderIntentService {
    public NotificationService() {
        super("ReminderService");
    }

    @Override
    void doNotificationWork(Intent intent) {
                 //Does work here
    }
}
```

WakeReminderIntentService is:

```
public abstract class WakeReminderIntentService extends IntentService {
abstract void doNotificationWork(Intent intent);

public static final String LOCK_NAME_STATIC = "com.companionfree.pricewatcher";
private static PowerManager.WakeLock lockStatic = null;

public static void acquireStaticLock(Context context) {
    getLock(context).acquire();
}

synchronized private static PowerManager.WakeLock getLock(Context context) {
    if (lockStatic==null) {
        PowerManager mgr = (PowerManager)context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);

        lockStatic=mgr.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, LOCK_NAME_STATIC);
        lockStatic.setReferenceCounted(true);
    }
    return(lockStatic);
}

public WakeReminderIntentService(String name) {
    super(name);
}

@Override
final protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    try {
        doNotificationWork(intent);
    } finally {
        getLock(this).release();
    }
}
}
```

and my Manifest shows:

```
<receiver android:name=".OnNotificationReceiver"></receiver>

    <service android:name=".NotificationService"></service>
    <service android:name=".WakeReminderIntentService"></service>
</application>
```

Can anyone figure out where I went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It would have helped if you would have posted the logcat error (with stacktrace) as well.

In any case I can see that this code is wrong and is probably giving you that error:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, OnNotificationReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
am.cancel(pi); // cancel any existing alarms
```

You are using a `PendingIntent` for a `Service`. But you need an `PendingIntent` for a `BroadcastReceiver`. Try calling `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()` instead:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, OnNotificationReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
am.cancel(pi); // cancel any existing alarms
```

Comment: Yeah, I found that error.  Still had problems though.  I finally got it to work with using the full class name both in the manifest and in the intent.